How to import Oracle unified audit spillover files generated by Data Guard physical standby database without switching over?
I know that I can use the DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT.LOAD_UNIFIED_AUDIT_FILES procedure to load the unified audit spillover files (*.bin) into the internal unified audit tables in an Oracle 19c database.  But, what if the database generating the files is a Data Guard physical standby?  Because the standby database is not writable, I can't log into the standby and load them by calling the procedure.
My question: Short of switching over the standby database to the primary role and running the previously mentioned procedure to load the spillover files, is there any other Oracle-supported way to get these files into the database?
I've seen a blog post or two about copying the OS spillover files from the standby to the primary and loading them there but this approach doesn't appear to be in the Oracle documentation or on MOS.  Also, OS spillover filenames aren't guaranteed to be unique between the standby and the primary, so accidentally overwriting spillover files on the primary with similarly-named files from the standby is a risk.
